# Why am I missing the UV Map option on certain Normal Map Vectors in Blender 2.8?

Tags: uv, normal-map, vector-mapping, vector

[image: On certain materials, the UV Map option becomes red, even though the same texture worked on other surfaces]

**I make content for a game called Trainz 2019. I'm currently working on a fictional train. How the textures are add works like this:
An image texture to the base color, a parameter texture to roughness, and an image texture connected via a normal map vector to normal. But for some reason, on select surfaces, the UV MAP option is missing in the Normal Map vector. It won't let me select anything and on some surfaces where I already applied a material, the UV Map option is red and if I click on it, the option disappears. The textures have to be added this way, or it'll trigger an error in-game, so I need to figure out why the normal map disappears and how to get it back.

I've tried quitting out of Blender 2.8 and re-opening it, I've tried deleting the material and starting from scratch, I've tried restarting the computer, but still the vector won't work on select surfaces.
[image: Standard method for how textures are applied to objects in Trainz 2019UV MAP option is missing******]**

Comment: the UV map must have been lost, have you checked in the Properties panel > Object Data > UV Maps?

Comment: I don't know where any of those are. I'm using Blender 2.8.

Comment: the Properties panel is the one on the bottom right, the Object Data tab is the one with the green triangle icon, check in UV Maps if you still have UV maps, if it's not the case, Blender don't know how to project the Image Texture on your object and you need to unwrap your object

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Your UV map is probably missing, check in the *Properties panel > Object Data > UV Maps*. If you don't see any UV map, you need to unwrap your object again so that Blender knows how to project the image on your object.

[image]